# Disable auto replacement of punctuation in SwiftUI TextEditor

Tags: swiftui

I am using a SwiftUI `TextEditor` view, on macOS 11, to edit some snippets of code. It changes punctuation as you type, which might be fine in English text, but is bad for code. For example, it changes `--` (two hyphens) to `—` (a dash), and inserts slanted quotation marks and other things.

How do I make the `TextEditor` work like a code editor, where you have all that stuff turned off?

This is what I have now:

```
TextEditor(text: $content)
    .font(Font.system(.body, design: .monospaced))
    .disableAutocorrection(true)
```

Comment: Have you firgured out what the problem is? I have the same problem now...

Comment: No. I ended up using `NSViewRepresentable` to wrap an `NSTextView`, which as the properties like `isAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled` that can turn this off.

Comment: Thanks, I have just made the same and was just frustrated to have the same problem there, that should solve it.

Comment: I'm late to the party here, but there is an awesome code editor available on Github: https://github.com/ZeeZide/CodeEditor